# Best sorting method for this?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

Question;

> You have to sort an array of bank transactions by date. Most of them
>   are in order (by date), only a few are out of order.
>
> Which sorting algorithm will you use between insertion sort, selection
>   sort and merge sort in order to take advantage of the fact that the
>   array is almost sorted?

My answer (not sure if its correct)

Assuming that N >= 5, i would go with Merge Sort since its avg. time complexity would be O(n * log n) which would be more efficient than insertion sort O(n^2). However, since multiple transactions will be on the same dates, insertion sort would be a good STABLE sorting method.

Which one is better in this case? Merge or insertion sort? Am i in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pick insertion sort, not because of stability, but because it's adaptive (see [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)) and will outperform due to the fact the input is almost sorted to begin with.

The meaning of this "adaptive" characteristic is that elements that are already in place are processed at O(1) time, and elements very close to their sorted position can also be considered O(1) (up to some k distance).